# NSMutableArray removeAllObjects issue

Tags: ios4, uitableview, nsmutablearray, sigabrt

I am trying to remove all the objects from the NSMutableArray and I am reloading the UITableView. But it produces SIGABRT in cellForRowAtIndexPath. The code is given below.

```
if ([nsMutableArray count] != 0) {

        [nsMutableArray removeAllObjects];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
```

It shows SIGABRT in

```
if (cell == nil) {

        cell = (UICustomCell *)[nsMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```

Help me to come out of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

to

```
if ([NSMutableArrayObject count] != 0) {
   [NSMutableArrayObject removeAllObjects];
   [tableView reloadData];
}

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = (UICustomCell *)[NSMutableArrayObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling instance methods (`count`, `removeAllObjects`, `reloadData`, `objectAtIndex:`) on *classes* (`NSMutableArray`, `UITableView`) instead of *object instances*.

Comment: Use the variables that you (hopefully) have. Like `NSMutableArray *myArray; myArray = ... ; if ([myArray count] != 0) { ... }`

Comment: OMG!!! I am using the object only. Just I used the class name here for the understanding purpose. I am using the objects of the classes mentioned in my code.